# Do photons and electrons of the same momentum diffract/interfere identically in same 2-slit experimental setup?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

If photons and electrons of the same momentum are sent, at separate times (e.g. first photons, then electrons), through a given experimental apparatus designed to show 2-slit diffraction/interference, would the photons exhibit the same diffraction/interference pattern that the electrons exhibit?  Or would a different apparatus be required for each kind of particle to exhibit 2-slit diffraction/interference?  I understand that the experiment might have different detectors for photons and electrons, but would the same two slits cause the same or different diffraction/interference for photons and electrons?

Comment: I'm realizing that the way I stated my question maybe left it unclear exactly what kind of answer I was looking for.  I had hoped the answer to the first question would be yes or no.  That is, light of a given momentum/wavelength either yields the same intensity distribution on a screen suitable for detecting those photons as electrons of that same momentum would yield on a screen suitable for detecting those electrons, or it does not.  Or, is the physics of the interaction of photons with the apparatus so different from that of the electrons that there's no reason to expect the same pattern?

Comment: Generally what differs between electrons and photons here is 1) interface conditions on the slit walls, and 2) polarization properties. These might affect the pattern on the screen, but it needs some actual computation to determine how exactly it would be affected.

Comment: Take as an example an electron with velocity on the order of 10^6-10^7 m/s (e.g. in/from a thermionic tube).  I think photons of equivalent momentum would be in the x-ray range.  If so, then I suppose it comes down to whether such x-rays and electrons have been put through the same apparatus and what the result was, or, as you (@Ruslan) suggest, if such an experiment has been modeled, correct?

Comment: Well, yes, I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing requires a somewhat advanced treatment. You'd need to do a few things:

1 . Photons and atoms travel at considerably different speeds, so you could only make it so that the photons could cross the atoms at a single point in space. I would think a single electron hitting a single photon would have an extremely small probability of interacting.

2. Raw isolated Electrons and Photons interacting is less commonly studied (from what I am aware of) than atoms (nucleus+electron), these electrons are bounded and typically have more interesting interactions with photons, because the photons can kick the electrons that are bound by the atom. The type that you are referring to is called "compton scattering."
3. If the electrons and photons did magically have a high probabilty of hitting eachother, then you had a single photon hitting a single electron, then you can have interactions between the photon electron that causes the outcomes to become correlated (entangled). So you might get a superposition of the photon being in one smaller frequency and the electron being scattered, and the photon being in a larger frequency and the other one being scattered.
4. After the location of the scattering event, you'd have an entanglement of these two possiblities, and then this is what would propagate through both slits. The photon possiblities will get to the slits first, each frequency will have its own interference pattern (which are different by the change in frequency which leads to a change in the evolving phase $e^{i E t}$). Now when both patterns hit the detector, I think you just get a sum of these interferences, which itself can look like an interference.
5. The interference of the electrons will happen after the event of the photons. This means that your detector at the end of the experiment could potentially collapse the entanglement information about the electrons before they even begin to interfere on the slit. If that happens, then no interesting interference happens in terms of the different momentums interfering, but you'd still see a classical interference pattern (but not an interference of interferences).

Answer (score 0):

So you should read about single photon and single electron "interference" experiments on this website.  It turns out that what you are taught in high school (or even reading in a few articles in Scientific American) is what is known as the classical interpretation ...... but it is disproven (but it is mathematically convenient and thus popular).

Famous scientists like Dirac and Feynman (and many others) stated/knew that each photon has a predetermined probability path to the screen, bright bands/areas have all the photons, dark areas none.  An excited electron in an atom or electrode is already strongly interacting with the EM field ... much before photon or electron emission.  This "virtual" EM field gives/determines probable paths.  The path Feynman path integral can be used to calculate probable paths .... it turns out the math coincides with the classical approach as well!

Comment: What exactly is disproven? Please give some references.

Comment: It is disproven that it takes 2 photons to meet at a point on the screen out of phase and thereby cancel each other (classical interpretation ).  Photons "interfere" even when they are initiated one at a time ... i.e. they "interfere" with themselves.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by same momentum? Electrons have mass and cannot travel the speed of photons. They can travel slower and their speed affects their momentum, which changes their wavelength per de Broglie wavelength (λ = h / p, where λ is wavelength, h is Planck’s constant, and p is momentum). As the speed of the electron increases, its momentum increases, and its wavelength decreases. This change in wavelength can impact how the electron interacts with the double-slit setup.
When electrons are sent through the double slits, they can create an interference pattern on the detection screen. This pattern results from the constructive and destructive interference of the electron waves. The spacing and characteristics of this pattern depend on the wavelength of the electrons, **which, in turn, depends on their speed**.
Electrons with higher speeds have shorter wavelengths. This can lead to a narrower interference pattern with smaller gaps between bright and dark fringes.
Electrons with lower speeds have longer wavelengths, resulting in a wider interference pattern with larger gaps between fringe. All photons travel at the same speed but their frequency will effect the pattern.

Comment: I think by same momentum the OP meant... same momentum! I.e. $\vec k_{\text{electron}}=\vec k_{\text{photon}}.$